# How to create jewellery ring configuration module?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1

I am going to create ring configure module for my project in Magento 2.1 where I will select diamond than diamond setting ring and in third step I will select selected ring size.

Exactly I want is in reference URL.

**Reference URL** is : http://www.brilliantearth.com/design-your-own-engagement-ring/?nav=1

If there is any module exist or have any possible approaches to achieve this task please share.

Thanks.